# Invalid argument error when scrolling across a cxgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tcxgrid

I have a delphi form with a cxgrid on it. The cxgrid is connected to a datasource/query which is looking at a database table.

When running the application and I scroll across the grid, the application crashes and displays the following error message.

> EVariantInvalidArgError with message 'Invalid Argument'.

Beside the CellDoubleClick event, there is nothing else happening on the grid.

Has anyone come across this before? If so can you advise anything?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you asked the component vendor? Is the component version relevant?

Comment: Is there DateTime field? And if is , is there date < 0(1.1.1900)?

Comment: Yes there are multiple DateTime fields, il double check the data to see if there is any bad data

Comment: When the exception occurs, have you tried viewing the stack (View | Debug Windows | Call stack) to see exactly where the exception occurs and what triggers it?  Btw, it seems rather unlikely that the problem is in the grid's code.